# Struts2 - jQuery Ajax forms Sends Data(POSTs) 2 times in jQuery Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I have a web application(J2EE+apache+struts2+jsp+struts2-jQuery plugin).

My problem is when I want to submit a form in jQuery Dialog with struts2-jQuery ajax method, it sends the form's data 2 times quickly after each other!! but when I put it outside the dialog, it works fine!

**-libs:**

**Struts2: struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar**

**Struts2 jQuery Plugin: struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.1.jar** (http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)

this is a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="orange" customBasepath="css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- JQuery --><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- ui-dialog-ChangePass -->
    <div id="dialogChangePassword" title="Change Password" style="display:none;overflow:hidden;">

        <sj:div id="actionMessageResult">
        </sj:div>

        <s:form id="frmChangePassword" action="changePassword">
            <sj:submit targets="actionMessageResult"/>
        </s:form>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dialogChangePassword').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Change": function() { 
                    document.getElementById('submitChangePass').click();
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

-And the result in FireBug:

[image]

**Also, when I click on sj:submit button directly, this problem happens again.**

**UPDATE: I simplified the example and put the whole page.**

Comment: Can you reduce the source into a single page and post the whole page, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Quaternion : Sure! I did that

Comment: I changed the "struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.1.jar" to "struts2-jquery-plugin-2.3.1.jar" and it worked fine!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to Work with Topics.

```
<s:form id="frmChangePassword" action="changePassword">
     <sj:submit targets="actionMessageResult" listenTopics="submitThisForm"/>
 </s:form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#dialogChangePassword').dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          buttons: {
              "Cancel": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              "Change": function() {
                       $.publish("submitThisForm")
              }
          }
      });
</script>
```

Why do you not use the `<sj:dialog />` tag?

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly.But the problem is not solved completely, when I directly click on sj:submit, it happens